# Change property of button from different class

Tags: ios, function, class, swift3

I have a button on a view controller - that view is of class "MainView" contains another viewContainer, whose view is of class "SecondView".

I have code in the secondView.swift file that calls a function in MainView.swift  `MainView().updateButton()`

The `updateButton` function in MainView calls correctly when it only contains a `print("called")` - however if I change the function to `button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue` then it crashes on that line with the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

How can I stop this crash?

Comment: You can use NotificationCenter. Here is a tutorial https://medium.com/ios-geek-community/pass-data-with-nsnotification-in-swift-3-73743723c84b#.7k8kpqfd7 .You will change a prooerty of a class instead of passing data according to example. You can change the code for your needs.

Comment: @theduman - this worked perfectly - put it as an answer and ill mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NotificationCenter. Here is a tutorial https://medium.com/ios-geek-community/pass-data-with-nsnotification-in-swift-3-73743723c84b#.jyxw619jd .You will change a property of a button instead of passing data according to example. You can change the code for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `MainView()` creates a new instance of the `MainView` class. The new copy of MainView won't have it's views loaded yet, and won't have anything to do with the instance of `MainView` that is on the screen. Don't do that.

You need a way to get to the existing instance of MainView.

If your `SecondView` is a child of `MainView` then you could get a reference to the parent view controller using it's parent property:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
  if let mainView = self.parent as MainView {
    mainView.updateButton()
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this but i'm not sure how to make SecondView a child of MainView?  When i use this code at the moment  it wants to put `as!`, and then returns the error   >Initialiser for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'MainView'.     If i use `as?` it works, but still crashes on the `button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue` line

Comment: Edit your question to show how MainView and SecondView are created and their relationship to each other. And add a "?" after as.

Comment: And edit your question to show the actual code that's crashing.